# Python code for generating random points not working!

Tags: qgis, python, random

I am trying to create some code to generate 10 random points within a vector layer's districts:

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
import ogr
import sys
import random
from shapely import wkb, geometry

Moz_no=layer.featureCount()

for i in xrange(Moz_no):
  district_tmp=layer.getFeatures(i)
  district=wkb.loads(district_tmp.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb())

  random_point_count=0

  sys.stdout.write("\r")
  sys.stdout.flush()

  while random_point_count<11:
    maxx, maxy, minx, miny = district.bounds
    random_point=geometry.Point(minx_+(random.random()*(maxx-minx)), (miny+ (random.random()*(maxy-miny))))
```

However, when I run the code, it gives me this error:

`TypeError: QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest request=QgsFeatureRequest()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'`

Could someone please help me, and explain what is going on?

Comment: Are you aware that you are duplicating existing code? See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doRandPoints.py

Answer (score 1):

The link @underdark used in the comment should give you plenty to review.  However, to address your error, the `getFeatures` command does not take an integer as a parameter. It takes a QgsFeatureRequest object.  See the [documentation](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a412ac9a3563e542485927bde03397962) for more details.

Instead of using an index, try something like:

```
for district_tmp in layer.getFeatures():
```

There's no need to get the count of features, enumerate through an xrange, and then select the feature by index.  Just enumerate through the features.

(Untested code so I might be missing something fundamental in your problem.)